# Python - How to resample a 2D shape?

Tags: python, geometry, 2d, resampling

I am writing a python script for some geometrical data manipulation (calculating motion trajectories for a multi-drive industrial machine). Generally, the idea is that there is a given shape (let's say - an ellipse, but it general case it can be any convex shape, defined with a series of 2D points), which is rotated and it's uppermost tangent point must be followed. I don't have a problem with the latter part but I need a little hint with the 2D shape preparation.

Let's say that the ellipse was defined with too little points, for example - 25. (As I said, ultimately this can be any shape, for example a rounded hexagon). To maintain necessary precision I need far more points (let's say - 1000), preferably equally distributed over whole shape or with higher density of points near corners, sharp curves, etc.

I have a few things ringing in my head, I guess that DFT (FFT) would be a good starting point for this resampling, analyzing the `scipy.signal.resample()` I have found out that there are far more functions in the `scipy.signal` package which sound promising to me...

What I'm asking for is a suggestion which way I should follow, what tool I should try for this job, which may be the most suitable. Maybe there is a tool meant exactly for what I'm looking for or maybe I'm overthinking this and one of the implementations of FFT like resample() will work just fine (of course, after some adjustments at the starting and ending point of the shape to make sure it's closing without issues)?

`Scipy.signal` sounds promising, however, as far as I understand, it is meant to work with time series data, not geometrical data - I guess this may cause some problems as my data isn't a function (in a mathematical understanding).

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: I don't exactly get how your data are. You should provide some example. But my feeling is that you are asking a way to create information that has been erased. Generally speaking that is not possible. Unless you make some assumption on a subspace in which you know the data live. For example, if you make the assumption that your data are all polygons, then it is possible to guess what polygon is closest to your low sampled data, and create a high sampled version of it. If you make, on the contrary, that they are smooth curves, then you can make other projection.

Comment: As you said, there are many functions in signals. Because there are many subspace on which you can project your data (it always end up to that. Maybe not linearly. But at the end, what you do is project your data on a subspace of the space of all possible curves: subspaces of curves made of sinus, of curves made of lines, splines, polygons, etc.), That is many assumption you can make about the shape of the data.

Comment: A general method, that can both recreate shap edge and smooth curve, can't really exist. Of course, if you reduce a bit the scope, and say that either the shape is really smooth (ellipse, parabolla, nothing more fancy) or on the contrary, really sharp (squares, triangles, hexagons, nothing more), then it should be possible to try first to guess which one it is. But with the information you gave, answer is simply that it is too late: once you have removed the information, you can't get it back.

Comment: @chrslg, I am not trying to get any erased data as this is obviously impossible. I have a set of (x, y) points, which (I know that of course, not the script) represent for example an ellipse (or other shape). However, I have only 25 points without any quarantee about their spread across the figure boundary, therefore I want to interpolate and add points between the starting ones. Of course, the final shape won't magically recreate what was happening between the original points but I would like to be able to control the interpolation (linear, polynomial,etc) and the spread (a point every ...px)

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I was not supposing that you were naive enough to expect to "unerase" data. But what I mean is that such an interpolation, is a way to "unerase" data, and therefore is not, theoretically possible. Or, to be more accurate, when you interpolate, you have to introduce a voluntary bias, and decide how to interpolate. Linear interpolation, for example creates some polygons, and would work well if your 25 points are the edges of polygons. The thing is that there are more than 1 shape that pass through 25 points.

Comment: You have some polygons. You have some splines. Etc. Chosing the "signal" function, that is the subspace on which you will project your 25 points, is choosing the interpolation.

Comment: I am not saying it is impossible. It depends on how accurately you can describe what kind of shape are possible. Again, if you say: "either it is some polygons, with no more edges than hexagons, or it is some conic section (ellipses, parabollas and such), then it should be possible to choose with 25 points. For example if a triangle exists that goes through all the 25 points, but only a 10-piecewise parabolla exists that pass not very far from them, then it is reasonnable to decide it is a triangle. But that is not an easy job. I don't think there is a magical existing function.

Comment: @chrslg, Ah, I see what you mean now!
I know that it's not likely that some function will handle all job by itself, I know what the shape "should be" so I can tell the algoritm to "make this segment a straight line" (linear interpolation), "make that segment an arc" (polynomial interpolation), etc. I have a general (intuitive) idea how it should work but I'm not sure which interpolation tool I should use - as I wore in a comment below, the `scipy.interpolation` module is so extensive that I'm a bit overwhelmed by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, what you want is to get an interpolated version of your original data.

The DFT (or FFT) will not achieve this purpose, since it will perform a Fourier Transform (which is not what you want).

Talking theoretically, what you need to interpolate your data is to define a function to calculate the result in the new-data-points.

So, let's say your data contains 5 points, in which one you have a 1D (to simplify) number stored, representing your data, and you want a new array with 10 points, filled with the linear-interpolation of your original data.

Using `numpy.interp`:

```
import numpy as np
original_data = [2, 0, 3, 5, 1] # define your data in 1D
new_data_resolution = 0.5 # define new sampling distance (i.e, your x-axis resolution)
interp_data = np.interp(
    x = np.arange(0, 5-1+new_data_resolution , new_data_resolution), # new sampling points (new axis)
    xp = range(original_data),
    fp = original_data
)
# now interp_data contains (5-1) / 0.5 + 1 = 9 points
```

After this, you will have a `(5-1) / new_resolution` (which is greater than 5, since `new_resolution < 1`)-length data, whose values will be (in this case) a linear interpolation of your original data.

After you have achieved/understood this example, you can dive in the `scipy.interpolate` [module](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) to get a better understanding in the interpolation functions (my example uses a linear function to get the data in the missing points).

Applying this to n-D dimensional arrays is straight-forward, iterating over each dimension of your data.

Comment: As of the DFT/FFT - it is a method that is used by, for example, `scipy.signal.resample` and as far as I know it can be used (from the mathematical point of view) for interpolation but for a time series data. No sure whether is can be used for such interpolation for (x,y) points not being an y=f(x), but I guess there should be a way of using it to solve the problem, like for example [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/59068/how-to-get-fourier-coefficients-to-draw-any-shape-using-dft)

Comment: Speaking of the `scipy.interpolation` module I guess one of the methods it offers would solve the problem and I'm just getting to dig through the docs but, to be honest, the amount of information and possibilities given by the package is a bit overwhelming and I'm not sure which interpolator should I start with.

Comment: @sokol07 The Fourier Transform (or DFT/FFT) is only internally used by these methods because what you actually need to interpolate is to multiply both your signal (data) and window (auxiliar function) in the frequency domain (aka multiplying fourier transform functions). In the time-domain, everything you should be concerned of to "enhance" your data resolution is defining a new set of points (a new x-axis, for example) where you want to get the missing points; and a function which calculates you the missing points in the new axis.

Comment: after some time I come back to mark your answer as correct and let you know that I am very grateful for your suggestion - I tried your suggestions, dived into the `scipy.interpolate` docs and I've found out that `splprep()` (with `per=1`) and `spllev()` are exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!